# How to fix regex to catch whatsapp exported text header with mobile and name mix

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I exported the whatsapp chat to use for machine learning, but having difficulties with non-utf-8 bitmap chars and header cleaning. 
some headers are mobile number, some name. Couldn't find regex to match all.
Also as mentioned, I couldn't find a way to parse this file as i get error parsing bitmaps with utf-8 encoding while opening wile like

```
with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

Example whatsap export:

```
10/14/18, 14:49 - ‪+90 999 555 55 55‬: <Media omitted>
10/14/18, 14:49 - ‪+90 999 555 55 55‬: 
10/14/18, 15:23 - Mehmet Senturk: <Media omitted>
10/14/18, 15:57 - Mehmet Senturk: <Media omitted>
10/14/18, 16:00 - Gülden Çağıl : done
10/14/18, 16:05 - Mehmet Senturk: 
10/14/18, 17:08 - Niyazi Şakiroğlu: Beyler yeni app hazır
10/14/18, 17:08 - Niyazi Şakiroğlu: Duuple AppStore ve playstore da yayında
10/14/18, 17:08 - Niyazi Şakiroğlu: Duuple
10/14/18, 17:08 - Niyazi Şakiroğlu: Görüşleriniz bekliyorum
10/14/18, 17:09 - Niyazi Şakiroğlu: <Media omitted>
10/14/18, 18:47 - ‪+90 999 999 99 99‬: Cok guzel app, hayirli olsun :))
10/14/18, 18:47 - ‪+90 999 999 70 99‬: Herkes indirmeli
10/14/18, 18:52 - ‪+90 999 999 99 99‬: İndirdim, birazdan inceleyip yorum yaparım....
```

I want to clean as:

```
done
Beyler yeni app hazır
Duuple AppStore ve playstore da yayında
Duuple
Görüşleriniz bekliyorum
Cok guzel app, hayirli olsun :))
Herkes indirmeli
İndirdim, birazdan inceleyip yorum yaparım....
```

I have following regex patterns but doesn't help.

```
mediaPattern = r"(\<Media omitted\>)" # Because it serves no purpose
regexMedia = re.compile(mediaPattern, flags=re.M)

dateAndTimepattern = r"(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)(,)(\s)(\d+:\d+)(\s)(\-)(\s+)[0-9A-Za-züğışçöÜĞİŞÇÖ\s]+[^\w]+(\:)?"
regexDate = re.compile(dateAndTimepattern, flags=re.M)

nonchar_pattern = r"[^\w\s<>:\-\/\,üğşçöıÜĞİŞÇÖ]+"
regexnonchar = re.compile(nonchar_pattern, flags=re.M)
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I don't understand why you need to escape bitmaps, if your regex engine supports full UTF8 (i.e. emojis are legal unicode chars, so what are the bitmaps you need to deal with?). Also, why can't you just exploit the presence of the colon (:) as a separator between header and payload to split each message? Are colons allowed inside whatsapp user names?

Comment: Hi, bitmaps are causing exception error in python that python cannot decode that lines which has bitmap. i couldn't figure out how to do that and i decided to clean first the bitmaps from the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is some error in your input file. If it contains bitmaps, then it is not a valid utf-8 encoded text file, but some other format that is replacing valid utf-8 emoji characters with bitmaps.

But the text data example you copied is correct utf-8, so I assume you can always use that as input.

Having sorted that out, the regular expression you are using will not match the data sample given, mostly because you are listing character classes explicitly and e.g. not including digits, so phone numbers fail to match in your data.

I would advise against this approach, and use universal captures for arbitrary fields, like user name and message payload. If needed, those fields can be cleaned-up after splitting the text file into records.

I.e. I would use this expression:

```
pattern = ^([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}),(\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s-\s(.*?):\s(.*)$
```

Which puts the date, time, user name and message payload in four capture groups. e.g.:

```
import re

rx = re.compile( "([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}),\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s-\s(.*?):\s(.*)" )

with open( "file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8" ) as fh:
    line = fh.readline()
    while line:
        data = rx.match( line ).group( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
        print( "date :", data[0], "time :", data[1], "user :", data[2], "msg  :", data[3] )
        line = fh.readline()
```

gives

```
date : 10/14/18 time : 15:57 user : Mehmet Senturk msg  : <Media omitted>
date : 10/14/18 time : 16:00 user : Gülden Çağıl  msg  : done
date : 10/14/18 time : 16:05 user : Mehmet Senturk msg  : 
date : 10/14/18 time : 17:08 user : Niyazi Şakiroğlu msg  : Beyler yeni app hazır
```

And I would carry out all data cleanup (like deleting emojis and  literals) after having parsed the text file structure.

Trying to do both things at once would require a very messy regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed and nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when building a tool to analyze WhatsApp chats.
I used a [Javascript library](https://github.com/Pustur/whatsapp-chat-parser/blob/master/src/parser.js) and they use multiple regex expressions which you should be able to use with Python as well:

Filtering general:

```
const regexParser = /^(?:\u200E|\u200F)*\[?(\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4})[,.]? \D*?(\d{1,2}[.:]\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\d{1,2})?)(?: ([ap]\.? ?m\.?))?\]?(?: -|:)? (.+?): ([^]*)/i;
```

Filter System Messages:

```
const regexParserSystem = /^(?:\u200E|\u200F)*\[?(\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4})[,.]? \D*?(\d{1,2}[.:]\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\d{1,2})?)(?: ([ap]\.? ?m\.?))?\]?(?: -|:)? ([^]+)/i;
```

Date:

```
const regexSplitDate = /[-/.] ?/;
```

Handle attachments, which are passed in "< >" even when you export the chat without attachments. (e.g. <media ommitted>)

```
const regexAttachment = /<.+:(.+)>/;`
```

For me that works for almost all languages (as the WhatsApp export is different relative to your system languages the format of the whole expression varies.
E.g. 11PM 02/12/12 vs 23:00 12/02/12)